# Signaling invalid parameters in C function

Tags: c, parameters

I have a function where I want to forbid the caller from entering invalid values (width or height <=0). In Java or C++ i would throw an exceptions, but there is no such thing in C. I read that one approach would be to create an enum with error codes and return them, however that would require changing the signature of the function (from void to int) and I would like to avoid that if possible. Current solution might lead to unpredictable outputs and it just does not feel right.

```
void set_dimensions(int width, int height, struct rectangle_t* rectangle){
    if(width<=0||height<=0){
        //The problematic part
        rectangle->width=1;
        rectangle->height=1;
        return;
    }
    rectangle->width = width;
    rectangle->height = height;
}
```

What is the best practice when handling a situation like that?

Comment: one C way is to crash the program (`abort()`). If the caller doesn't want the program to crash, the caller can simply not do that.

Comment: Check the values at the point of input, bearing in mind "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: "throw an exceptions, but there is no such thing in C." As above, for non-recoverable errors I always include a (variadic) function that will report and/or log it and exit the program.

Comment: There is no single best practice. It depends on the situation. Even exceptions is one tool that may not always be the best. Another option is to log/print an error message, possibly combined with aborting the program. Yet another approach is to set a global error code and/or message which the upper layers of the program can then check.

Comment: "*I read that one approach would be to create an enum with error codes and return them*" --> that sounds like something written about C by a Java programmer.  Specifically the `enum` part.  Sure, you can do that, but the C standard library and many other real-world examples just use an `int`, or occasionally another type not specific to the purpose of error reporting.  That would be more conventional.  Often these do double duty by also serving to return an ordinary result.

Comment: Why don't you want to change the return type? It's hard to give recommendations if we don't know what your requirements are, and using the return value is the standard method.

Comment: What about adding an out parameter by which to convey an error / status code?

Comment: Add an error state to the struct that contains width and height to prevent  use after an invalid setting.

Comment: There is also a Linux way. Your function may return different flags depending on the result of the function call. For example, if the function runs fine, then the OK error code is returned. If there is some error, you may signify it by the corresponding error code. The same process may go with the parameters validation.

Answer (score 3):

> Current solution might lead to unpredictable outputs and it just does
> not feel right.

1. Use `assert()` to validate the post-conditions, or log a message to `stderr` and call `abort()`.

```
/* NOTE: assert() will be disabled in non-debug builds. */

assert (width > 0 && height > 0)

/* Or */

if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, /* Error message */ );
    abort();
}
```

2. Take in an out-parameter as a pointer, and use that to return an error code.

```
void set_dimensions(int width, int height, struct rectangle_t* rectangle, int *err_status)
```

3. Change the return type of the function from `void` to `int`. You could then follow the POSIX convention to return -1 on failure, and 0 on success, or something similar.

```
/* 
*  @return Upon successful return, set_dimensions() shall return 0.
*          Otherwise, -1 is returned to indicate failure.
*/
int set_dimensions(int width, int height, struct rectangle_t* rectangle) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: 4. Use a global variable (same idea as errno, but using errno can cause some confusion/conflicts). Only advantage over 2 and 3 is no change to the signature, but it does introduce a side effect...

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate something similar to a Java exception with `setjmp` and `longjmp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf error;

struct rectangle_t { int width, height; };

void set_dimensions(int width, int height, struct rectangle_t *rectangle)
{
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
    {
        longjmp(error, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        rectangle->width = width;
        rectangle->height = height;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct rectangle_t rectangle;

    if (setjmp(error))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "set_dimensions fail\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    set_dimensions(0, 1, &rectangle);
}
```

Comment: One absolutely can do this, but I would hardly recommend it.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, because it's perfectly correct - I'll just leave a note that it should be considered primarily of academic interest and almost certainly never used.

Comment: @Useless I agree that in this case it is like killing flies with a bazooka, but setjmp is not limited to an academic use at all ... one example is to cleanly exit a complex recursive function.